# How does the assignment of colnames work "behind the scenes"?

Tags: r

(I hope that this question hasn't been asked before).
For convenience I am using abbreviations for functions like "cn" instead of "colnames". However, for colnames/rownames the abbreviated functions only work for reading purposes. I am not able to set colnames with that new "cn" function. Can anyone explain the black magic behind the colnames function? This is the example:

```
cn <- match.fun(colnames)
x <- matrix(1:2)
colnames(x) <- "a" # OK, works.
cn(x) <- "b" # Error in cn(x) <- "b" : could not find function "cn<-"
```

Comment: See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#special-calls (section Replacement functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, echasnovski, for the link to that great website.
It has helped me a lot to better understand R!
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#replacement-functions

In R, special "replacement functions" like `foo<-` can be defined. E.g. we can define a function

```
`setSecondElement<-` <- function(x, value){
  x[2] <- value
  return(x)
}
# Let's try it:
x <- 1:3
setSecondElement(x) <- 100
print(x)
# [1]   1 100   3
```

The `colnames<-` function works essentially the same. However, "behind the scenes" it will check if x is a data.frame or matrix and set either names(x) or dimnames(x)[[2]]. Just execute the following line in R and you'll see the underlying routine.

```
print( `colnames<-` )
```

For my specific problem the solution turns out to be very simple. Remember that I'd like to have a shorter version of `colnames` which shall be called `cn`. I can either do it like this:

```
cn     <- match.fun(colnames);

`cn<-` <- function(x, value){
  colnames(x) <- value
  return(x)
}
```

More easily, as Stéphane Laurent points out, the definition of `cn<-` can be simplified to:

```
`cn<-` <- `colnames<-`
```

There is a minor difference between these approaches. The first approach will define a new function, which calls the `colnames<-` function. The second approach will copy the reference from the `colnames<-` function and make exactly the same function call even if you use `cn<-`. This approach is more efficient, since 1 additinal function call will be avoided.

Comment: you can do 'cn<-' <- 'colnames<-' with backticks instead of ' (I don't know how to type that here)

Comment: Even easier. Thank you! You can use the escape character (backslash) to write backticks:  \`cn<-\` <- \`colnames<-\`